# What is the direction of the "normal force"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

What would be the direction of normal and friction forces when a rod is falling which was initially kept upright on a table?

[image: Fall8ng Rod]

Comment: If I understand your question at all, the normal reaction, by definition should be along the common normal of the surfaces in contact(in this case the rod and table), while the friction force will act tangential to the surfaces in contact, on both bodies(in opposite directions). In case of the rod, the frictional force would try to prevent the base of the rod from slipping, as it falls.

Comment: A normal will act on the rod i just wanted to know its direction in the above case

Comment: Note that *normal* is a mathematical synonym of *perpendicular*.  For example, we speak of an orthonormal basis.  That might help to understand the term.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: Normal and friction force]
I added some color to your image. Hope that helps :)

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force) the "Normal Force" is perpendicular to the "ground" (table in this case).

> ..the total ground reaction force can be divided into two components: a normal force **perpendicular** to the ground and a frictional force parallel to the ground.

where the "ground reaction" would be the resultant force of the "Normal" and "Frictional" forces which makes the rod not only rotate while falling, but also moving its center of mass away from the contact point.